# What is the reason of inaccuracy of operations on float numbers?

Tags: floating-point

I wonder why in JavaScript

```
0.1 + 0.2  // return 0.30000000000000004

4%0.1 // return 0.09999999999999978
```

http://jsbin.com/oHISAfU/1/edit  (Example)

In C the math.h library fmod function

```
printf("%f", fmod(4.0,0.1));  // print 0.100000
```

http://ideone.com/RG5Wyv (Example)

And in Spotlight (search feature in the Mac OS X ~ I already submit bug report) that support math operation

```
4%0.1 = 0.1
```

[image]

Comment: Recommended reading: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Another recommendation: Goldberg's [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163).

Comment: Not a recommendation, but there are infinitely many floating numbers, and only, say, $2^{32}$ binary numbers to represent them.  Indeed, there are infinitely many rational numbers between 0 and 1, ($1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, \dots$) and therefore there must be some holes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because 0.1 = 1 / 10 = 1 / (2 × 5) cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.  [This happens in C too](http://ideone.com/jBEiRh):

```
 printf("%.20f", fmod(4.0,0.1));
```

prints `0.09999999999999978351`.

Specifically, the only numbers that binary floating point can represent exactly are [dyadic fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_fraction) of the form *a* / 2<sup>*b*</sup>, where *a* and *b* are integers.  Even more specifically, for [IEEE single precision floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), *a* must be between -2<sup>24</sup> and 2<sup>24</sup> and *b* must, in effect, be between -151 and 104.  (Or at least approximately so; there are some tricky special cases like denormalized numbers.)  For double precision floats, the ranges are wider, but even so, a fraction like 1 / 10 cannot be represented exactly, because the denominator is not a power of two.

Answer (score 8):

Ilmari Karonen gets it right in the other answer. But it gets even worse than that: arithmetic operations involving floating-point numbers don't necessarily behave the same as operators we're used to from mathematics. For instance, we're used to addition being associative, so that $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$. This doesn't generally hold using floating-point numbers, and for a given format it's not hard to come up with counterexamples. Not exactly relevant to the question you asked, except to illustrate that you should never assume floating point calculations are going to be exact.

Comment: In particular, for sufficiently large $a$ and sufficiently small $b > 0$, it's quite possible that $a + b = a$ in floating point.